Convert this DE into homogenous
I was given these two differential equations under a Homogenous DE lecture and was asked to solve it. How do in convert these DEs into homogenous DEs?
$$
(2x-y-3)dx-(x+4y+3)dy=0
$$
$$
(2x-3y+2)dx+3(4x-6y-1)dy=0
$$

Is the coefficient of $dy$ in the first equation correct?

My mistake. I just fixed the first equation.

You can transform the first equation into a homogeneous one with the change of variables $(x,y)=(x'+1,y'-1)$.

I see. So I can sub those and solve this as normal. (2x'-y')dx'−(x'+4y')dy' = 0

And once i'm done solving, i sub them back

You want the constant term to be zero for the system to be homogenous. A guess might be $x^\prime=x-a$ and $y^\prime=y-b$ with $\mathrm dx^\prime=\mathrm dx$ and $\mathrm dy^\prime=\mathrm dy$. So then you want that $2(x^\prime+a)-(y^\prime+b)-3$ and $(x^\prime+a)+4(y^\prime+b)+3$ to have no constant term. So, you can substitute $x^\prime=y^\prime=0$ and have these expressions be $0$, so in other words, you want to find $a$ and $b$ such that
$$\begin{gather*}
2a-b-3=0\\
a+4b+3=0
\end{gather*}$$
Hope this helps. :)
